# Nested double sum does not converge

Tags: equation-solving

I am quite a beginner, and have the following problem. I have a sum that comes from Poisson distribution and for each index there corresponds a binomial-type sum. I try to find its root for the probability that is in the binomial-type sum (as a function of other variables/parameters) so that I could plot it.

But I get a warning that says that Hypergeometric PFQ does not exist and the parameters are not consistent, and that the sum does not converge. I should appreciate any help.

```
Clear[c, d, a, p]


stochprob[d_, a_, c_] := 

p /. FindRoot[
Sum[Exp[-a]*(a^h)/(h!) Sum[
   Binomial[h, k] p^k * (1 - p)^(h - k) 1/(k + 3)^2, {k, 0, 
    h}], {h, 0, Infinity}] == (1 - d)*c, {p, 1/3}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure does the code below produce correct results, but it does provide some numbers reasonably fast. (I guess not because of the negative `p`, but may be this code is useful anyway...)

I made several changes of the code in the question:

- using `NSum` instead of `Sum`;
- calling `NSum` (or `Sum`) once with specification of two ranges;
- defining a function, `BiSum`, that takes numerical arguments only.

Note that I set the method for `NSum` to something that would produce results faster. It is probably a good idea to experiment with using different methods and/or using different precision goals.

```
Clear[BiSum]
BiSum[a_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
 NSum[Exp[-a]*(a^h)/(h!) Binomial[h, k] p^
    k*(1 - p)^(h - k) 1/(k + 3)^2, {h, 0, Infinity}, {k, 0, h}, 
  Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "ExtraTerms" -> 20}, NSumTerms -> 200]

BiSum[1, 1, 1, 1/3]

(* 0.0962654 *)

Clear[c, d, a, p]
stochprob[d_, a_, c_] := 
 p /. FindRoot[BiSum[a, c, d, p] == (1 - d)*c, {p, 1/3}, 
   MaxIterations -> 20]

stochprob[0.1, 1, 1]

(* -3.98788 *)
```